# Assigning a string to a 2D array

Tags: c, string, arrays, 2d

```
char in[100], *temp[10],var[10][10];
int i, n = 0,
double val[10];
var[0][]="ANS";
```

I want to assign a string to var[0][0,1,2] which is 'ANS', but does not work and i cannot figure where i am wrong about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have sort of answered your own question.  You want to assign var[0][0,1,2,3] to "ANS" right?  Well "ANS" is an array of characters, ans[0,1,2,3] (don't forget the null terminator).  So you have to assign each one individually.  In C strings aren't a data type, they are just an array of other variables (chars to be exact).  What you can do instead is:

```
strcpy(var[0], "ANS");
```

Which will do the byte-by-byte copy for you.

There are some pitfalls to strcpy, however.  First, the destination char array (var[0] in this case) must be large enough to contain the string.  It will not check this for you (it can't, actually) so if you are not careful you can cause a buffer overflow.  Also, the source must be NULL terminated.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps instead using,

```
strncpy(var[0], "ANS", 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
var[0][] = "ANS"
```

Compiler tries to assign "ANS" to var[0][0] which is a place for only one char.

Therefore, you should use strcpy function. strcpy will copy char-by-char.